# What's the core topic of mathematics?

Tags: functions, soft-question, set-theory

I'be been reading this book, [How to Think like a Mathematician](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/6220915). Within the book, the author states that:

> Most high-level mathematics is about sets and the functions between them [. . .] In effect, we can view sets and functions as the mathematician's building blocks.

Is that statement true? Are sets and functions the building blocks of mathematics, and does that make them the core?

Comment: Not less not more than saying that brushes and paints are  the core for a painter !

Comment: So that's a yes!  Cool, so does that mean that all of mathematics can be reduced to sets and functions?

Comment: This is an excessive point of view influenced by the "categorical approach". What is lacking is the "**soul**" behind that. Another comparison : you will meet people saying that human life is like animal life : "being born, eating, escape dangers, reproducing and then dying" ; this is not false, but happily, it's much more than that !!!

Comment: @JeanMarie Please elaborate. What is missing, what else do you think is at the core of mathematics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement requires some historical context. In brief, though, I'd say this applies to much of modern mathematics, but not all. And even for the fields where it applies, it doesn't tell you that much.

Back in the eighteenth and early nineteeth century, math was almost about "numbers and space". That is, the main fields were geometry, algebra, and calculus (including things like differential equations). Number theory also fits neatly into this slogan.

If you look at original sources from this period (Euler, Lagrange, Gauss, etc.) you'll find a heavy emphasis on formulas, plus the geometrical aspect. Nowadays, for example, the theory of algebraic equations is virtually always presented in terms of fields and automorphism groups. But when Abel and Galois did their work, they dealt with algebraic expressions and permutations of variables that left them invariant.

During the late nineteenth and early twentieth century, a shift in viewpoint occurred, due to the work of mathematicians like Cantor, Dedekind, Hilbert, and many other too numerous to list. This was the set-based approach: sets and functions. This culminated in the realization that almost all math can be "coded" into formal set theory (say with the Zermelo-Fraenkel axioms).

The fact that you can "code" some piece of math into set theory doesn't always tell you a great deal about it. In many cases however, the new viewpoint led to major advances.

Starting in the mid-twentieth century, category theory made its appearance. This emphasizes sets and functions even more, and also abstracts from them. The basic idea is that to study structures of some kind (topological spaces, vector spaces, ...) you need at look at both the structures and the maps between them.

This is a very skeletal description. The history of math books by Jeremy Gray are a good resource. Also the [MacTutor website](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/). And of course the "History" section of Wikipedia articles on various fields).

Answer (score 1):

Well, at a first approach to mathematics, you must think this way, it is the more "healthy" way to begin. You should start with the naive Cantor set theory, and then you should study a little on the Zermelo-Fraenkel approach.

But when you are going deeper into the maths, you will discover that Sets is only one Topos between other alternatives, and that there are more than functions and sets.

Comment: Only one "Topos"? Interesting, what is a Topos? What's the deeper idea behind sets and functions?

Comment: First f all, I am not an expert at all on that subject. A topos is kind of like the idea of sets, where you can have subsets and stuff like that, but it's more flexible and can work with other things too. So with a topos, you can do things like split it up into smaller pieces, which they call "subobjects", and you can do things like define functions between these pieces. But the cool thing is that a topos can include all kinds of things, not just sets. They have a notion of "and", "or", and "not" for different kinds of objects. It's kind of like logical reasoning, but more general.

Comment: Is this where the idea of Topology comes from? Or is topology derived from the idea of Topos?

Comment: To my knowledge, it has nothing to do with it

Answer (score 0):

Its definitely one way to think about it. For example, in Real Analysis you study the set of all real (continous, differentiable,...) functions (or the Real Numbers as a set and the functions between them), in Linear Algebra you study Vector Spaces which are sets (with additional structure) and the linear maps between them. So I would say the statement is true to a certain extent, given that anything that you study in maths can be interpreted as a set.